# Is the Elektra film in the same continuity as Marvel's The Defenders?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, canon, the-defenders-2017

In the movie *Elektra*, with Jennifer Garner, she was called "The Treasure", in which she was an assassin trained by Stick that could resurrect the dead.

Does that story have anything to do with the Elektra in *Marvel's The Defenders*, the TV series ?

Comment: The Elektra movie doesn't share the same continuity as the Defenders. She's a crossover from the Daredevil TV series.

Answer (score 9):

Both the Elektra from the film (who also appeared in the Daredevil movie) and the Elektra from the TV series are based on the same comic book character. But there is no continuity between the film and the series: both are independent adaptations of the same source work.

Comment: Can you back that up with some evidence?

Comment: @Valorum the 2003 Daredevil movie, and 2005 Electra spinoff movie, are not part of the MCU. The Netflix shows are. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daredevil_(film)): "*A television series of [the same title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daredevil_(TV_series)) [Daredevil] **but set in [a different continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe)**, by Netflix and Marvel Studios, followed, premiering in 2015.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Wikipedia is a fan-written encyclopedia and hence can say anything *without justification*. If I felt like spending the effort, I could go and change it right now so that it says the precise opposite

Comment: @Valorum: you could, but I am the Immortal Iron Finger, sworn to protect the kingdom of Wi’K’ipedia, and I will wage an edit war with enough fury to make a dragon tremble.

Comment: @Valorum Kevin Feige stated that Iron Man (released 2008) was the first of the Marvel Cinematic Universe movies, it has also been stated before that Daredevil on Netflix was the first time Marvel has brought Daredevil to screen. Therefore Neither the Daredevil or Elektra movies are part of the continuity, just as Eric Bannas Hulk, the first 5 Spidermen, the Punisher Movie and Fantastic 4 are not.

Comment: @RichardC - If you have interviews that confirm that, what you've written would make an excellent answer.

Comment: @Valorum there are literately hundreds of quotes and stories and interviews with Kevin Feige, various actors, directors, writers and Stan Lee that state that the MCU began with Iron Man and only consist of films produced by Marvel Cinema. Infact just recently Feige clarified that the new Venom Movie Sony are producing is not an MCU movie and so there will not be a Venom Spiderman crossover. But dont take my word for it marvels own website states the films that are part of there universe https://marvel.com/movies/all. I dont see Daredevil or Elektra in that list?

Comment: @RichardC - You keep telling me about these interviews but I haven't seen a link to, or a quote from any of them. My advice is to find one and use it as the basis for an answer.

Comment: @RichardC - For the record,  Elektra (2005) *is* on that list; https://marvel.com/movies/movie/13/elektra

Comment: Why did they make the defenders look so lame? They made Elektra and daredevil look like kids.

Comment: @Jenishayoung: Jennifer Garner [played a 13-year-old who dated the Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/13_Going_on_30)! (She also worked with Ant-Man’s ex-wife and Ulysses Klaw for some reason.)